# Lambda/Linq Error "an Item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq, lambda

"An item with the same key has already been added" is the error I'm getting. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for any help.

```
 using (var Customerconn = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> Empsource = Customerconn.tblOutOfOfficeLogs

                      .Join(Customerconn.tblEmployees,
                      l => l.EmployeeID,
                      emp => emp.EmployeeID,
                      (l, emp) => new { ID = emp.EmployeeID, Name = emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName }) 
                .Distinct()
                .ToDictionary(empl => empl.ID, empl => empl.Name);

               //Set combo box source to Empsource


        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are only getting a single row for each unique EmployeeID?  That would cause this error.

Comment: Ok. Thanks it works now. I had Distinct in the wrong area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you are sure that no duplicate EmployeeIDs exist you may cause duplicates in the join statement if the same employee holds more than one log. Isn't that your problem?

Does the following work?

```
        Dictionary<int, string> Empsource = tblOutOfOfficeLogs
            .Select(x => x.EmployeeID).Distinct()
                       .Join(tblEmployees,
                             l => l,
                             emp => emp.EmployeeID,
                             (l, emp) => new { ID = emp.EmployeeID, Name = emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName })
                       .ToDictionary(empl => empl.ID, empl => empl.Name);
```

Comment: I can reproduce the error if I mock the objects from the statement and introduces lists rather than tables. Unique employees in that table but a duplicate employee id in OutOfOffice log throws the exception you mention. But I can eliminate it by selecting distinct logs prior to joining.